# set_error_handler with PRIVATE-static-method callback

Tags: php

Is it possible to use private static method as a set_error_hander callback?

This works fine:

```
<?php
    class DisplayErrors{

        private static $email_address = 'myemail@mail.com';

        public static function error_handler($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars) {
            // send error to email;
        }

        private static function toEmail(){
            // set_error_handler('self::error_handler');
            set_error_handler(__CLASS__ .'::error_handler');
        }

    }
```

This has no effect nor error:

```
<?php
    class DisplayErrors{

        private static $email_address = 'myemail@mail.com';

        private static function error_handler($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars) {
            // changed to private static method;
        }

        private static function toEmail(){
            // set_error_handler('self::error_handler');
            set_error_handler('self::error_handler');
        }

    }
```

I have also tried:

```
set_error_handler(array('self','error_handler'));
// no effect no error
set_error_handler('&self::error_handler');
// invalid callback
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The problem is that the string is evaluated internally within `set_error_handler()`, it doesn't have access to the original scope. So it can't call private methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP 7.1 or higher, the new [closure::fromCallable](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php) method will allow you to do this.

```
    private static function toEmail(){
        set_error_handler(Closure::fromCallable('static::error_handler'));
    }
```

`Closure::fromCallable()` evaluates the callable argument in the scope where it's called, so it can accept private and protected methods when used within the class.

Comment: Works great with 7.2. Many Thanks